# Lotus Notes Search on Web without change in URL

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino, lotus, lotusscript

Is there a way in Lotus Notes to search a view without using URL commands.

Thanks.

Comment: Not enough information on what it is you are trying to achieve. Do you want to search via Browser? Or something else?

Comment: I agree with Simon.  You need to restate your question to make clear exactly what you want to do, and why you think it should be done "without URL commands".  Everything on the web requires a URL, so I don't understand what alternative you could possibly have in mind.

Comment: I am looking for something similar to POST method in the form. Instead of using SearchView?query=xxxxx in the URL. like you can have added one search text box added to the viewtemplate form and when you type in your query results are shown in the same page and the URL remains same.

Answer (score 2):

You would need to use Ajax and some Javascript for that. I would suggest to use jQuery, there you already have the function jQuery.get() that will do all the heavy lifting for you.
More info plus examples at http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/

Call the search, perhaps a Lotusscript agent that you pass the search criteria to and returns the results formatted as HTML, then simply insert the return value into the DIV on yoru form where you want to display it.
Or you can have the agent return the results as JSON, and then you can parse it locally in the browser and display it the way you want it.